# Scheme fold map and filter functions

Tags: list, filter, functional-programming, scheme, predicate

I am learning how to use higher-order functions in scheme. I get the idea of using higher-order functions, however I am having trouble using them. For this learning exercise, I would prefer to only use some combination of filter, fold, and/or map.

For example, I want to construct the set difference between two lists call them A and B. I am defining set difference as x such that x is an element of A but x is not an element of B. I only want to use the functions map, filter and fold. For example:

Let A = (1 8 6 2)

Let B = (5 7 9 1 6)

The set difference of A and B would be (8 2)

The idea is to construct a new list by iterating over the elements of A and seeing if an element of A equals an element of B, if so don't add a to the new list; otherwise add a to the new list.

My algorithm idea goes something like this:

Let neq be "not equal to"

1. For each a in A and b in B evaluate the expression: `(neq? a b)`

   For a = 1 we have:

   (and (neq? 1 5) (neq? 1 7) (neq? 1 9) (neq? 1 1) (neq ? 1 6))
2. If this expression is true then a goes in the new list; otherwise don't add a to the new list. In our example `(neq? 1 1)` evaluates to false and so we do not add 1 to the new list.

Pretty much my entire procedure relies on 1, and this is where I have a trouble.

1. How do I do step 1?
2. I see that in step 1 I need some combination of the `map` and `fold` functions, but how do I get the `and a neq b` distributed?

**EDIT** This is the closest sample I have:

```
(fold-right (trace-lambda buggy (a b c) (and (neq? a b))) #t A B)
|(buggy 3 5 #t)
|#t
|(buggy 2 4 #t)
|#t
|(buggy 1 1 #t)
|#f
#f
```

The above shows a trace of my anonymous function attempting to perform the (and (neq? a b)) chain. However, it only performs this on elements in A and B at the same position/index.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `fold` will always evaluate all the applications along the list, in Scheme, and no short-circuiting is possible. [`ormap` is a much better fit](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html) here. `fold-right` has the additional drawback of not being tail recursive (unlike `fold-left`). :)

Comment: @WillNess: See my answer below that short-circuiting *is* possible. You just need call/cc. In fact, strict functional programming languages without call/cc seem to miss something.

Comment: @Marc will do. :) ah, the non-local exits. of course it changes everything. not necessarily just through call/cc BTW, in Common Lisp there's the `return-from`, or just `go`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simplified version of `member` is easy to implement using `fold`, of course:

```
(define (member x lst)
  (fold (lambda (e r)
          (or r (equal? e x)))
        #f lst))
```

Now, with that, the rest is trivial:

```
(define (difference a b)
  (filter (lambda (x)
            (not (member x b)))
          a))
```

If you want to amalgamate all that into one function (using your `neq?`), you can do:

```
(define (difference a b)
  (filter (lambda (x)
            (fold (lambda (e r)
                    (and r (neq? e x)))
                  #t b))
          a))
```

Comment: This definition of `member` won't short-circuit on the first match, though.

Comment: @WillNess It also doesn't return the item being matched, only true or false. But it serves the OP's purpose well enough.

Comment: @WillNess Also (while you're here), the default avatar generation system isn't Gravatar's fault; SO chose to use identicons for default avatars. If you need to blame something, blame the identicon algorithm.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. For your 1st, you're absolutely right. For the 2nd, I don't *need* to blame anyone, I want to be spared the pain of seeing the occasional high-resemblance graphics. I wrote to SO, they said it's Gravatar that's producing the identicon. Gravatar uses the algorithm which produces *rotational-4-symmetry* figures which are bound to resemble the xxx with high probability. They could use another, but that's the one they stick with. Even just mirroring one of the quadrants would be enough.

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell, `fold` is capable of short-circuiting evaluation because of lazy evaluation.

But in Scheme it is impossible. That's why **in Racket** e.g., there's a special function supplied for that, [`ormap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._ormap%29%29), which *is* capable of short-circuiting evaluation. IOW it is a special kind of `fold` which must be defined explicitly and separately in Scheme, because Scheme is not lazy. So according to your conditions I contend it is OK to use it as a special kind of `fold`.

Using it, we get

```
(define (diff xs ys) 
  (filter 
    (lambda (y) 
      (not (ormap (lambda (x) (equal? x y))     ; Racket's "ormap"
                  xs))) 
    ys))
```

If your elements can be ordered, it is better to maintain the sets as ordered (ascending) lists; then `diff` can be implemented more efficiently, comparing head elements from both lists and advancing accordingly, working in linear time.

Answer (score 1):

Using Racket:

```
(define A '(1 8 6 2))

(define B '(5 7 9 1 6))

(filter-not (lambda (x) (member x B)) A)

 ==> '(8 2)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I do not want to use member, only some combination of map, fold, and/or filter.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus `(filter-not g xs)` == `(filter (lambda(x)(not (g x))) xs)`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it is possible in Scheme to implement `member` on top of `fold` that short-circuits on the first match:

```
(define (member x lst)
  (call-with-current-continuation
    (lambda (return)
      (fold (lambda (e r)
              (if (equal? e x)
                  (return #t)
                  r))
            #f lst))))
```

Comment: yes, but, it's not the fold that's short-circuiting.  potayto, potahto, you might say. :) still...